# Node real time debugging log

Tags: node.js, debugging, logging, verbose

Im experiencing high latency during when Im benchmarking my web app. Usual response time is around 700ms but under heavy load, it climb to 15s. I want to debug where is the bottleneck.

Most basic method I think will help is to have something like superverbose output and there I can see in which part it freezes or spend most of the time.
For now Im connected with `node inspect` and Im looping `pause` and `cont` to catch where we are at the moment but this is not enough.
Is there some way to make all debuging output visible and forward it for example to file?

I know this will be huge amount of output.

UPDATE: Attaching screenshot of my desired verbouse output, this is what Im doing now with pause / cont but I want uninterupted flow of this output:
[image]

Comment: Maybe the decent solution is to use a log manager like graylog to which you can direct the logs you produce. To do something more crude, you can insert `console.time()` between blocks of code and see in which block the times are exaggerated.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, this console.time looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I ended with automation of my first method. I created expect script sending `n` (next step) 100000 times so it walks entire page load. First I need to pause whole page in different debuger window (do not close it because it resume execution on exit) `node inspect localhost:9229` > `debug> pause`. And then I can run expect script (in new window) piped to file `./nodebuger.exp 2>&1 | tee -a node.log`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn node inspect localhost:9229
expect "debug>"

set times 0;
while { $times < 100000 } {
    send -- "n\r"
    expect "debug"
    set times [ expr $times+1];
}
```

And there (after some cleanup), when I see bunch of lines with n character, I know that the previous step is still in progres (so its slow):

[image: log output]

---

Good article about How to enable debugger fast on any (also live) env without interupting: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/live-debugging-node-js-apps-at-the-command-line-cd5b58f883e1

```
$ ps aux | grep node
user 23254  0.0  0.0    0     0 ?        I    08:53   0:00 node /script.js
$ kill -SIGUSR1 23254 #this is not killing the process, just enabling debugger
$ node inspect -p 23254
or 
$ node inspect localhost:9229
```